# PostgreSQL function check if field is CSV

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, csv

I can accomplish this with PHP in the end, but it would be more elegant to have it in the SQL. I have no choice but to use PostgreSQL for this project and I have never used it before, so...

There is a table '*test_results*' that contains the columns:

```
sample_id(text) | test_result(text) | sessiontime(bigint)
```

Another table has information that includes the *sample_id*, but some have had multiple tests run. When that happens the *sample_id* field is populated with a CSV list of *sample_id*s. Not all of these *sample_id*s exist in the *test_results* table. There is also no way of knowing how many tests have been run.

If there is only one *sample_id* it will be in the table and should be returned. Otherwise the field of CSV needs to split and checked to see if it exists and since only one test_result need be returned the one with the latest *sessiontime*(which is epochtime) need be returned.

I have been over this many ways and my code has now become a jumble of unworkable ...
Guidance would be appreciated. I can always go back and do it in the PHP if I need...

EDIT TO BE CLEAR.. SOMETHING LIKE THIS:

```
   DROP FUNCTION get_test_results(text);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_test_results(sample_id TEXT) returns
table(test_results text) as $$
BEGIN
    IF position("," in sample_id) THEN
        -----DO SOMETHING to 
    ELSE
    SELECT test_results FROM test_results WHERE sample_id = sample_id ORDER BY sessiontime DESC;
    END IF;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This not functioning yet.... needs to split_part(sample_id, ','::text, 1) then get all the results but on the one with the most recent sessiontime.

Comment: "a jumble of unworkable . . . ".  Alas, your code would probably be cleaner if you had used a junction table to store the sample ids in a table with one row per test and per sample id.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question, some sample data (as `insert into`) and the expected output based on that. Formatted text please, [not screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: There are numerous JOINs in place... all of tables?

Comment: You should fix your db schema first. Remember: fields should contain only primitive data types.

Comment: I wrote the example in the edit off the top of my head after having spent 12 hours using PostgreSQL for the first time... please help me out here. Is TEXT not a primitive data type? Or are you referring to the csv being in the field... basically I have spent two hours since your comment about fixing the schema with no example to guide me on how I went wrong... can you point to a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL is an excellent choice and very versatile for things like this.

First of, to determine if your sample_id is a single value or a list of values:

```
-- (sample_id ~ '^ *\d\+ *$') returns true if there is one number only
SELECT CASE WHEN sample_id ~ '^ *\d\+ *$' THEN sample_id::int END
```

Then, to open up the list of ids in a comma-separated list of samples you can unnest the array returned by string_to_array:

```
SELECT i
FROM unnest(string_to_array(sample_id, ',')::int[]) i
```

You can use that for either single or multiple numbers (since there is just one value, you'll get only one row).

Comment: ERROR: cannot cast type text[] to integer

Comment: @Lithodora fixed the bug